# Have to enter google sites through second-level domain

Tags: g-suite, google

I'm having the same problem as [this guy](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=30b917bdc6edb3b4&hl=en). I own two domains hosted on google sites, mydomain.com and mydomain.net. When I go to mydomain.com, it redirects me to the site located at www.mydomain.com (this is the desired behavior). This used to also work on mydomain.net, but now when I go to mydomain.net, I get a Google 404. To see the content, I have to go to **www.**mydomain.net. As far as I can tell, the DNS settings and Google apps settings for both domains are identical. Does anybody have any idea about what could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps requires you to have a primary domain name, but then they allow you to specify domain aliases. From the dashboard page, click Domain Names and add mydomain.net as an alias for mydomain.com and then I think Google will recognize the domain name for the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Redirects are done by the web-server hosting the system. There is no magic redirect from *mydomain.net* to *www.mydomain.net*.

The correct way of gaining this behaviour is by running a small web-server or reverse proxy, that will then redirect all *mydomain.net* to *www.mydomain.net* either in a script or in the server configuration.

Since redirects are minor operations, you can exploit any service (free or paid). You could consider using a webhop service.

Answer (score 0):

A simple CNAME record could do.